# Does Nginx unquote/unescape URL characters before matching?

Tags: regex, nginx

When I want to match a URL with spaces in it, the spaces may be encoded as `%20` or `+`. In order to match this in an Nginx regex, what pattern do I need to use?

Does Nginx pass the URL through as-is?

`(?:%20|\+| )`

or, does Nginx do some unquoting or unescaping first?

`(?:\+| )`

or is `+` normalized?

Answer (score 1):

Though I didn't find any references in the Nginx documentation with a quick look, from my testing, Nginx normalizes HTTP codes as unicode such that '%20' is matched with a '\s'.  '+' is already in unicode and doesn't need to be normalized.

Eg. `/route/the%20test`

Should match with `(?:\s)`

However, I tend to lean on the safer side and use something like: `(?:(\s|\%20))`